# Perform CellContent Click of DataGridView in c#

Tags: c#

I have to perform a cellcontent click event from a button (called Next button) which will invoke cellcontent_click event for the next row.That next button is not inside the grid view.

How can i do it. Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to raise the event, but you can always call the event handler explicitly. This is, however, seen as bad coding practice, so you should put the common code in its own method:

```
void dataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    CommonClickBehaviour(e.RowIndex);
}

void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if ((dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index + 1) < dataGridView.Rows.Count)
        CommonClickBehaviour(dataGridView.CurrentRow.Index + 1);
}

void CommonClickBehaviour(int rowIndex) {
    // respond to the event or psuedo-event here.
}
```